# Tkinter opening two windows instead of 1, crashes if I refer to root window

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, tk-toolkit

When I run my program it produces two windows. One called Tk and one called This is my Title. It draws the combo box and label in the titled window but draws the image label in the Tk window.

Now I know I need to specify (window, image=photo) in the image label for it to draw in the titled window...however if I do that I get a crash and it reads so:

Error:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=960x540 at 0x19B6AFD6948>
About to set Photo for first time
Class Photo is: pyimage1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t:/Highlight/ImageDetect_Py/ImageDetect/New_Test.py", line 54, in <module>
    photoLabel = Label(window, image=photo)
  File "C:\Users\Tommy\Anaconda3\envs\OCV\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Tommy\Anaconda3\envs\OCV\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
Exception ignored in: <function BaseMySQLSocket.__del__ at 0x0000019B691E2828>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tommy\Anaconda3\envs\OCV\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 133, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Tommy\Anaconda3\envs\OCV\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 121, in shutdown
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
Exception ignored in: <function BaseMySQLSocket.__del__ at 0x0000019B691E2828>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tommy\Anaconda3\envs\OCV\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 133, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Tommy\Anaconda3\envs\OCV\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 121, in shutdown
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Working Code (opens two windows, Tk and titled):

```
import time #Import Time
import concurrent.futures #Import for multithreading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Process, pool  #Import for multiprocessing
from tkinter import Label, Entry, Button, W, E, S, N, NW, NE, SW, SE, Tk, Canvas, ttk, mainloop
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw #Import Pillow for TKInter image conversion
import sys
import urllib.request
import threading
import queue
import numpy as numpy
from pathlib import Path

#Layout GUI
window = Tk()
window.title('This is my title')
width_of_window = 1280
height_of_window = 720
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
tk_x_cord = (screen_width/2) - (width_of_window/2)
tk_y_cord = (screen_height/2) - (height_of_window/2)
window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width_of_window, height_of_window, tk_x_cord, tk_y_cord))
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#Callback function for combo boxes
def callbackFunc(event):
    print('New Element Selected')

#Camera Select Box
cameraComboLabel = Label(window, text='Choose Camera:')
cameraComboLabel.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=25, pady=20, sticky=W+N)
cameraComboBox = ttk.Combobox(window, values=["Camera1", "Camera2"], state='readonly')
cameraComboBox.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=1, pady=20, sticky=W+N)
cameraComboBox.current(0)
cameraComboBox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackFunc)

#Load last saved snapshot as placeholder image
lastImage = Path('snapShots/192.168.0.13.jpg')
image1 = Image.open(lastImage)
image1 = image1.resize((960,540))
image1 = image1.convert('RGBA')
print(image1)
print('About to set Photo for first time')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1) #Store Tk image for use in GUI
print(f'Class Photo is: {photo}')

#Create image label
photoLabel = Label(image=photo) #If I type Label(window,image=photo) it crashes
photoLabel.grid(column=3, row=5, padx=25, pady=5, sticky=W+S)


window.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: _"class Work:(edited out as not the problem)"_ - how do you know it's not part of the problem? If it's not part of the problem, you shouldn't be calling it in your [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley you're right sorry will edit. And because it crashes way before that  class is called by the combo box being selected.

Comment: Please also remove all of the unnecessary import statements, and all of the other statements that aren't necessary to reproduce the problem (eg: `window.resizable`, etc).

Comment: thank you @BryanOakley you telling me to remove imports made me think to try that on my project, I copied the code into a new file and the imports one by one andfound I had left an import of an old gui class in there that was causing the issue!! All good now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I don't get any errors and it only opens one window

try updating any libraries you use and see if that fixes the problem

[Here is a photo of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H6kp.png)

Comment: hmm do you think it may be because im using the Anaconda Tkinter? interesting thank you for testing it out! Just curious if you specify window in the image label does it still work too?

Comment: I don't know about the anaconda Tkinter but I installed mine using pip, also what should I set window to in the image label?

Comment: so change photoLabel = Label(image=photo) to photoLabel = Label(window, image=photo)  which is technically what it should be. I have reinstalled tk so have latest version but no change. cheers :)

Comment: ah my goodness so it turns out it was a file in my imports! I was importing an old gui class I had made but wasnt using it anywhere, somewhere it conflicted!! Bryan Oakley telling me to remove all imports from my post that I didnt need. I then copied and pasted one by one into new file and I found which import was causing it!